# Can we calculate the frame dragging force of the Earth?

Tags: general-relativity, earth, rotation

Although clearly this force would be significantly greater with a rotating black hole, is it still possible to calculate this drag for say a satellite orbiting the Earth?

Comment: What is *frame dragging force*?

Comment: SO when a large mass rotates, it drags spacetime with it, thus for satellites orbitting the Earth, I wondered if it is possible to calculate how much further they are 'dragged' due to this force?

Comment: Not only can it be calculated, but it was measured by [gravity probe B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_B).

Comment: Oh fantastic, is there any way we can prove this (ie how would we calculate it?)

Comment: @SarahJayne: I never got further than the Schwarzschild metric I'm afraid (there isn't much call for general relativity in colloid science :-). However it's such a routine calculation that it must be easily Googlable.

Comment: I have found many sources stating the final result however none showing the calculation unfortunately! But thank you anyway! :-)

Comment: @SarahJayne: it's described in [A First Course in General Relativity](http://www.amazon.co.uk/A-First-Course-General-Relativity/dp/0521277035/ref=sr_1_2) by Bernard F. Schutz starting on page 298 (in my 1999 edition). It's also bound to be somewhere in the bible aka [Gravitation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Gravitation-Physics-Charles-W-Misner/dp/0716703440/ref=sr_1_1) by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler.

Comment: Right okay thank you! I'll have a search through my library and see if they have it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned in the comments, the frame-dragging of a satellite orbiting the Earth was measured by the [Gravity Probe B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_B) mission. The gyroscopes on the Gravity Probe B measured a frame-dragging drift rate of $−37.2 \pm 7.2$ mas/yr , where the theoretical prediction was $−39.2$ mas/yr (mas = milliarcsec). The results can be found in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3456).

The theoretical frame-dragging value follows from the **Schiff equation**
$$
\boldsymbol{\Omega} = \frac{GI}{c^2r^3}\left( \frac{3(\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot \boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{r}}{r^2}-\boldsymbol{\omega} \right),
$$
where $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the position vector of the satellite, $I$ is the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) of the Earth, and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the angular velocity of the Earth. You can see this equation in the figure below ([source](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/g/gp-b)):

[image]

This equation can be derived from gravitomagnetism; see [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0411129), [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3346), or Weinberg's *Gravitation And Cosmology*, section 9.6 (Precession of Orbiting Gyroscopes).
In order to find the average frame-dragging, we have to integrate the equation over an orbital revolution. Fortunately, Gravity Probe B has a polar orbit, for which the average value becomes
$$
\boldsymbol{\Omega}_\text{av} = \frac{GI\boldsymbol{\omega}}{c^2r^3}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}(3\cos^2\theta - 1)\text{d}\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\text{d}\theta} = \frac{GI\boldsymbol{\omega}}{2c^2r^3},
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$.
We have, using this [source](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/MomentofInertiaEarth.html),
$$
\begin{align}
I &\approx 8.02 \times 10^{37}\,\text{kg}\,\text{m}^2,\\
\omega &= \frac{2\pi}{86164\,\text{s}} = 7.29 \times 10^{−5}\,\text{rad}\,\text{s}^{-1},\\
r &= 6371 + 642 = 7013\,\text{km}.
\end{align}
$$
Combining this, I find $\Omega_\text{av} = 40.8$ mas/y, close to the value cited in the Gravity Probe B paper.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, but how do you get your final solution in terms of mas/y? Doing this calculation I get approx 1.944 (x10^18) ?

Comment: @SarahJayne You should get $6.28\times 10^{-15}$ rad/s. Since $1\;\text{rad} = 180\times 3600\times 1000/\pi\;\text{mas}$ and $1\;\text{y} = 3600\times 24\times 365.25\;\text{s}$, you get 40.8 mas/y.

Comment: Okay, I can't quite work out where I've gone wrong then: 

I got $$ \frac{GI\boldsymbol{\omega}}{2c^2r^3} = \dfrac{9.81 \times (8.02 \times 10^{37}) \times (7.29 \times 10^{- 5}) }{2 \times (3 \times 10^8) \times 7013^2}  $$
$$ \approx 1.944 \times 10 ^ {18} $$

Actually I have just realised that I forgot to square 'c' however that still only produces a solution of: 6478742530 ??

(Sorry if I'm missing something painfully obvious!)

Comment: @Pulsar Hi I was wondering if you could assist me with something related to this post? At Mercury's perihelion, that part of it closest to the Sun sits at (45998761000 m) from the center of the Sun and has a velocity of (58967 m/s). However, I suspect that because of frame-dragging that part of Mercury should have an actual velocity of (58967.000001203807824 m/s). Can you help me prove it?

Answer (score -1):

This is really an add-on to the excellent answer by Pulsar.  Sarah Jayne never got her units worked out fully because she had the wrong "g" and used "r" in km instead of meters.  I solve the equation that she has posted using the universal constant G = 6.67e-11 m3/kgs2 as:

radian/second = 6.67e-11*8.02e37*7.29e-5/(2*3e8*3e8*7013000^3) = 6.27e-15 rad/s

Then Pulsar showed the conversion to mas/yr

Comment: This is more of a response to [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95361/can-we-calculate-the-frame-dragging-force-of-the-earth#comment197266_95418) than an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, but I am not allowed to respond to a comment because I don't have enough reputation points.  Please feel free to move my answer.  I think it has value because of the different learning styles of people - people like Sarah and myself feel more comfortable when we can see numbers in a solution and not just variables.