# How much percent of the speed of rotation of the solar surface at the equator is due to frame dragging effect?

Tags: astrophysics, rotational-kinematics, sun, angular-velocity, frame-dragging

Frame dagging effect is interesting and my particular interest is does this rotation could be compared with the law of motion of planets in a system similar to our Solar system and also can we measure how much of the rotation of the solar surface at its equator is due to this frame dragging effect?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as not comprehendable.  Perhaps you should re-write to ask "Is GR frame-dragging a significant effect on the behavior of the Sun's coronal disc?"

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95361/can-we-calculate-the-frame-dragging-force-of-the-earth) you can calculate the numerical value, then you can compare it to the angular velocity of the Sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame dragging is significant only in the immediate vicinity of an extremely intense gravitational field. Ordinary stars and planets, etc. do not have strong enough gravity to do this in an amount big enough to measure.

Comment: And yet, the Sun does cause a measurable precession of the orbit of the planet Mercury.

Comment: @general electron, that is not due to frame-dragging.

Comment: As a data point:  In a scale where the time dilationof a GPS signal due to orbit speed is $7$ , the offset due to frame-dragging is calculated to be $0.00000003$